# pg_dump error: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-dump

I need to use the pg_dump command to dump my development db to a file and then upload this to my heroku hosted rails app.

I am unable to use the rails command

```
  "heroku db:push"
```

I have been asked by Heroku support to use the pg_dump tool to send transfer databases between cleint and server.

I just ran this command:

```
  pg_dump -U XXXXX -w app0521_development
```

It output the entire contents of my database to the console

But this command for some reason fails:

```
  pg_dump -U postgres -w app0521_development > test.dump
```

with this error message
     -bash: test.dump: Permission denied

Comment: can you log into the database anywhere using any tool?  if so, what?

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit to my post in response to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will either need to make a special folder and give the postgres user/group access read+write to it, or you should be able to send it to /tmp/test.dump;

```
pg_dump -U postgres -w app0521_development > /tmp/test.dump
```

Most of the time (at least on Ubuntu), the /tmp folder has "read+write+execute" for everyone.  Just a warning...  if it's got sensative data, it's out there for everyone that can get on that box.  So, clean it up!  And also of note, the /tmp folder has the "t" flag set.   The "t" indicates that only the user (and root) that created a file in this directory can delete that file.

If you want to create your own folder, just google "chgrp" - and then of course you need to give "read-write" to the group.

Comment: Excellent that worked. What I found was that on my system Mac OSX I can execute this command no worries:  ----> pg_dump -U postgres -w app0521_development > /Users/AM/Documents/test2.dump -- this will put the file into that folder. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped some...  I didn't even think about you being on Mac OSX.  As future reference, it's always good to include the OS you are running on and the version of PostgreSQL you are using.  Both of those things will help people to answer.  Best of luck.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Sorry I didn't think about that! Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

> with this error message -bash: test.dump: Permission denied

Try putting a > before the test.dump and see what happens.  I assume that is the backup file you want to have?   That sounds like filesystem permissions issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks. got the same error message with a >